# О родстве названий этносов

Tags: этимология

Есть некоторые научные, а скорее, псевдонаучные теории о том, что якобы русские и этруски - это родственные народы. В качестве доказательства приводят схожесть названий. Действительно ли в названии этих народов есть общий корень "-рус-", или это случайность? А также меня интересуют пруссы.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если **этруски** и русские - родственные народы, то это должно наблюдаться в языке. А этого как раз нет (кроме созвучия названий).  Родственные связи этрусского языка являются дискуссионными. Составление словаря этрусского языка и расшифровка текстов продвигаются медленно и по сей день далеки от завершения. Этрусский язык считается языком-изолятом и не имеет признанных наукой родственников. Одной из гипотез о возможном родстве этрусского является версия Старостина и Дьяконова о родстве этрусского языка с вымершими хурритским и урартским. Другие исследователи продолжают настаивать о родстве этрусского с анатолийской (хетто-лувийской) ветвью индоевропейских языков. Учитывая **немногочисленность известных этрусских слов** и лишь *ограниченное знание этрусской грамматики*, все эти предположения в очень большой степени **спекулятивны**.

Главное, чтó при наивном, любительском отношении к делу остается незамеченным и чем грешат многочисленные псевдонаучные сочинения, — это непонимание того, что никакие языки не остаются в ходе времени неизменными. Никто не будет отрицать, что этруски жили примерно 25 веков назад. Так что даже если предположить, что это русские, то они говорили на русском языке двадцатипятивековой давности, а не на современном языке. А разница между нынешним языком и языком, который был двадцать пять веков назад, колоссальная!

Что касается **пруссов**, то о происхождении их этнического самоназвания prūss, prūsai («прусс», «пруссы») и регионима Prūsa («Пруссия») среди исследователей нет единого мнения. По замечанию некоторых исследователей романтиков, самоназвание страны пруссов (Prūsa — произн. как «Пруса») созвучно древнему имени страны фризов (Frusa — «Фруза»); вероятно, как раз не пожелавшие отступиться от язычества фризы, будучи главными союзниками «мятежных» саксов, и принесли на территорию Погезании, Помезании и Вармии прототип самоназвания древних пруссов.
По другой версии, название «Пруссия» возникло из гидронима Русс или Русне, то есть названия правого рукава дельты Немана, или же из «Руссна» — прежнего названия Куршского залива, которое можно прочесть на карте Пруссии, составленной в 1576 г. немецким историком и картографом Каспаром Генненбергером (англ.)русск. (1529—1600).
Третья версия самоназвание древних пруссов выводит из коневодства, которым славились древние пруссы. *Прус* означает 'конь' в готском языке, а также 'кобыла' в старославянском.

Как видите, схожесть названий может натолкнуть на ложный след и совершенно не означает, что народы, носящие эти названия, родственны. К тому же специалисты сами подчеркивают, что не обладают достаточным объемом информации, чтобы делать такие "сенсационные" выводы. Нужны доказательства, а их-то у историков-любителей и нет.

Answer (score 2):

Этру**сс**ки - это очередной шедевр от Задорнова. 
Этим всё сказано. Честно говоря, не заслуживает оно развернутых комментариев.

А вот насчет пруссов... 
Начнем  от печки. Поскольку этнохороним "русские" не имеет ясной этимологии (посмотрите в Интренете, столько всего понаписано) и версии строятся в ориентации на разные языки-источники (от скифских до норманских), то и разговоры о родстве его с ещё менее понятным самоназванием далёкого от всех народа ещё менее состоятельны. Вообще пруссы - исчезнувший народ балтийской группы, родственен литовскому. Таким образом сторонникам родства пруссов и русских надо копать в сторону балто-славянских корней топонима Русь или этнохоронима руссы. Но такие версии сейчас непопулярны. Хотя можно порыскать, глядишь что-то и найдётся.
Касательно же самого происхождения названия пруссы я повторяться не буду. **Olsa** даёт всё более чем исчерпывающе.

Answer (score 0):

> Вот спасибо, порадовали. Я-то дкмал, что он, типа, шутит, а он оказыввается с титиретиками общается. Не иначе как на спиритическом сеансе. Или это у него диагноз такой "теоретик"?

---

Нормальные живые теоретики ("мертвые" - это которым сказать нечего. От них один мало чем подкрепленный сарказм). Я видел видео об одном таком теоретике + есть книжечка (ну официально 100% достоверность ей конечно никто не даст) где выложен этрусский алфавит и значения букавок. Было бы желание и не было бы лени можно было и проверить. :)

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Когда нечего сказать - это не теоретики мертьвые, а мертвые теории. Мертворожденные. А мертвые теоритики как раз очень плодовиты. Вот и Задорнов весьма плодовит. Вся беда в том, что плоды его словоблудия - ниже всякой критики.

Comment: Мдяя, филологи "народ не прошибаемый" (я сам не филолог, я программист. Сюда захожу потому что интересно и это). Что ж вы так на Задорнова вешаете ярлык теоретика. Он не ученый, он критик-юморист и просто разносит идеи которые подчерпнул у других, которые исследовали эти вопросы. И "сто пудов" ни один здесь хаящий Задорнова даже хоть чуть чуть не исследовал этих тем, не читал и ничего не сопоставлял. Но при этом все утверждают, что это полная "фигня"! Для 100% утверждения нужны доводы и факты, но и для отрицания они так же нужны. А иначе слепые вера или неведение.

Comment: Вообще-то это я программист. 
А вот кто вы - это ещё "будем посмотреть".  
Задорнов может и юморист, но когда его афонаризмы начинают эксплуатировать неюмористы становится немножко не по себе. Говорить конкретно не приходится, поскольку ни одной фамилии кроме Задорнова вы не назовете. А на любую критику вашей теории всегда найдётся реплика о непрошибаемых филологах.

Кстати, не про вас ли тут?))))
http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-13337

Comment: "На всякий чих не наздавствуешся". Мало какие дикие теории придумают люди - что ж, кидаться их все изучать?  
Я, например, математик, но несколько книг по этимологии все же читала. Поэтому имею представление о том, что такое научный метод. Рассуждения Задорнова и рядом с ним не стояли. Человек берет произвольную часть слова (корень, суффикс, несколько букв, вырванных из того и другого) и по таким обломкам пытается обосновать родство смыслов...

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо за ссылку - очень хорошо написано!

Comment: Да, спасибо за ссылку! Статья написана как раз "мертвым теоретиком" - сплошной, ни чем не подкрепленный, сарказм. И скорее она не про нас, а для вас, способных делать утверждения на «пустом месте». Такие статьи делаются просто: берутся действительно бредовые авторы (такие теоретики есть наверно в любой области науки) вполне понятно высмеиваются + туда добавляются действительно стоящие рассмотрения идеи которые под эту марочку легко сливаются (без сколько нибудь должной критики – ПРОСТО!).

Comment: Прежде чем гнать на Задорнова, для начало ознакомьтесь с трудами Фоменко и Носовского (кроме книг есть серия фильмов «История наука или вымысел?», а так же Валерия Чудинова (смотрел лишь фильм «Язык Титанов»(могу шибиться в названии) – не так сильно как у Фоменко, но достойно внимания), которые по моему мнению были необоснованно слиты в этой статье. Этимология конечно вещь 50/50 и должна быть чем-то подкреплена или может выступать как косвенное подтверждение других исторических теорий. Поэтому нельзя на одной только этимологии утверждать были ли Этрусски предками русских или нет.

Comment: Прежде чем знакомиться с "трудами" Носовского и Фоменко рекомендую получить справку от психиатра. Хотя становится понятно, кого вы называете живыми теоретиками. Радует, впрочем, что вы сами понимаете, какого поля ягода этот Чудинов.
Интересно было бы услышать, а вы всех, кто не согласен с вами называете мертвыми теоретиками? И только ли их?
К. Ю. Старохамская - не филолог. Советую ознакомиться с её статьями прежде чем ярлыки клеить. Не Фоменко, чай.
ЗЫ С бредом Фоменко и иже с ним я знаком уже лет тридцать. Мнения об этой шайке шарлатанов, как понимаете, от вашей протекции не изменил.

Comment: 1. А вам к невропатологу - проблемы с внимательностью. "Мертвыми теоретиками"(разжевываю) представил людей не могущих опровергнуть теории и доводы стольже подкреплеными фактами, а дейстуют лишь на эмоциональную сторону публики высмеивая и понося оперируя слабыми косвенными, зачастую натянутыми аргументами. Они не могут привести конкретное опровержение почему то или иное невозможно, вот и начинают горланить.

Comment: 2. Труды Фоменко (кроме моей логики) посчитал достойными рассмотрения один мой знакомый человек, увлекавшийся историей (не школьная программа).Конечно не археолог но вел чтение отдельных писателей истории, считающихся класиками так и современные журналы вроде "вестника истории" (Уж незнаю печаталась там ли там  К.Ю.Старохамская) Этот человек знаком с белыми пятнами истории и согласен с тем что эта теория очень многое ставит на свои места. Для вас конечно не показатель, но для меня это мнение достаточно авторитетно(Но раз уж вы 30 лет знакомы с "шайкой" фоменко" то возможно вы даже ровестники)

Comment: 3. В психушку забирают тех кто не способен к критике, само критике и их восприятию. И туда я за справкой  пойду лишь тогда, когда  увидев вразумительное опровержение что на камушках Чудинова действительно нет следов буковок складывающихся в конкретные слова или что у Морозова и Фоменко с Носовским луна неправильно вертелась, я все равно буду "говорить что они хорошие".

Comment: 4. Я ни разу не сказал что, все что выдвигают эти теоретики это правда. Я твержу что это ТЕОРИЯ! Теория это еще не правда, а лишь кандидат. У этих теоретиков есть ядро их теории, а у большинсва критиков основным доводом является лишь слово "БРЕД", а так же все родственные по смыслу слова и производимые с ними тексты.

Comment: 5.  Я посмотрю кто такая К. Ю. Старохамская и что она пишет. Я люблю  новые для себя имена и интересные идеи и рассуждения.

Comment: Заодно посмотрите в словаре, что такое "теория".
И чем она отличается от бреда.
Кстати, к вопросу о критике. Покажите мне хоть одно слово у всей этой гоп-команды (Чудинова, Фоменко, Носовского и прочих) в отношении серьёзных ученых, которое было бы не синонимично слову "бред" или "лженаука". Если не найдёте, вам придётся признать, что к восприятию критики не способны как раз вы и ваши авторитеты.

Comment: @behemothus, да не спорьте, Вы же видите, какого поля эта ягода. Таким людям "альтернативные" теории всегда будут нравиться своей "оригинальностью", мнимой простотой, а также самим фактом непризнания со стороны классической науки.  
И, знаете, неплохо, что такие люди есть - ведь раз в 100 лет и палка выстрелит! Теоретически возможно, что будет придумана какая-нибудь революционная теория, которой на первых порах придется пробивать бастионы классики. Было это уже в науке, ох, как было!

Answer (score 0):

Задорнова люблю давно (лет 30 уже). И сейчас иногда его слушаю, хотя, честно говоря, примелькался. Его лингвистические изыскания никогда всерьёз не воспринимала. Это просто юмор. Не думаю, что он родоначальник т. н. "народной этимологии". Думается, дилетанство у нас в крови. Все знают, как правильно лечить, учить, судить и т. п. А вот и новая мода: все "умеют" находить "скрытое значение" слов и объяснять их происхождение. Так что притензии к Задорнову считаю необоснованными.

Comment: Хорошо бы он как-то четче обозначал, что его "сказки" - это ирония над народной этимологией. А ведь он никак этого не утверждает! Так что разные люди, склонные к умственным шатаниям, получают в его лице поддержку своим странным идеям. Может, и невольную с его стороны...

Comment: Боюсь, что он уже сам верит в то, что говорит.

Comment: Единственный плюс- надежда, что люди начнут искать информацию о том, правдива ли его "этимология".

Comment: Мда... Задорнов безумно популярен даже среди участников нашего портала.)))

Answer (score -2):

Задорнов тоже не с потолка взял, а от других теоретиков. Этрусский язык, который "не читается", был прочитан одним из ученых изучавших древнерусское письмо. Этрусский язык является более древним, чем сейчас преподаваемая староверами "буквица"(если не изменяет память) из 49 букв.

Comment: Вы путаете "язык" и "алфавит". Язык не состоит из букв, хоть 49, хоть 33, хоть 26. Язык состоит из слов и грамматики.  
Честно говоря я не слышала о "буквице" как алфавите. Разве что на сомнительных по научности сайтах.   
По моим скромным сведениям до "кириллицы" была "глаголица"

Comment: Вот точно попутал - "глаголица" - спасибо. Неважно из чего состоит язык, здесь важна родственная связь письменности этрусков с русским языком. А что до сомнительности, так уже некоторое время много чего из устаявшегося ставится под сомнение, в том числе и история со всеми вытекающими. Недавто товарищь Путин так же признал что Куликовская битва собственно была между русичами.

Comment: Вот спасибо, порадовали. Я-то дкмал, что он, типа, шутит, а он оказыввается с титиретиками общается. Не иначе как на спиритическом сеансе. Или это у него диагноз такой "теоретик"?

Comment: Ужасно не люблю, когда Задорнов ударяется в этимологию. Такое ощущение, что он сам в это ерунду верит. Смущает слабые зрительские умы.